# How to import a library on Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web-applications, import

I am currently working with Ember.js.

I have some issues importing some library into my application. First I downloaded this library http://www.acme.com/javascript/Clusterer2.js after that I was reading all the documentation in this [Importing Javascript](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/).
But my main problem is I still don't know how to use it. I was searching and after long hours I found that in the application.hbs in the template that you generate with `ember g template application` that is in the folder ~\app\templates I have to make a call with this action:

```
{{outlet}}
{{link-to nameoftheLibrary}}
```

But I am still not much familiar with this. I can't call any action from the library that I am trying to use.

Comment: save Clusterer2.js file into vendor folder. and in ember-cli-build.js file include the below line app.import('vendor/Clusterer2.js')..and then you can start using like  var clusterer = new Clusterer( map )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### First Preference: Ember Addon

Preferably your JavaScript library will be an ember add-on. Then you can install it by simply typing:

```
# ember install <addon name>
```

This will usually take care of all importing that you need to do. The JavaScript code will be included in your compiled Ember app.

#### Second Preference: bower package

If there isn't an ember add-on, then you can use bower:

```
# bower install -S <bower package name>
```

Then you need to add the dependency in your `.ember-cli-build` file:

```
/*jshint node:true*/
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
      // snipped out some stuff
      });

  // this library is in your bower_components/somelibrary/somelibrary.js file
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/somelibrary/somelibrary.js');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

#### Last Preference: Manual import

If you can't find your required library as an ember add-on or bower package, you're going to have to import the library manually.

**Step 1: save the javascript folder in your `vendor` folder**

Save your Clustererer2.js file in a folder like `vendor/clusterer/clusterer2.js`.

**Step 2: Modify your `.ember-cli-build` file to include this in your compiled Ember app**

Modify your file like this:

```
/*jshint node:true*/
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
      // snipped out some stuff
      });

  app.import('vendor/clusterer/clusterer2.js');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

**Step 3: Make JSHint happy about the new Global**

You're going to have to make `jshint` happy about the new global variable you're going to reference in your code. Add it in your `.jshintrc` file:

```
{
  "predef": [
    "document",
    "window",
    "-Promise",
    "Clusterer"
  ],
  "browser": true,
  "boss": true,
  // snipped a lot of stuff
  "esnext": true,
  "unused": true
}
```

Notice that after the `"-Promise"` entry I added the `Clusterer` line?

**Step 4: Rebuild Ember app and use your new library**

Now that you've included the javascript file in your compiled output, you should be able to reference it in your code.

Comment: Oh Thanks! you I am gonna do it manually because the library is not there. The ` "esnext": true ` is not in my .jshintrc I have to add it? Thanks for amazing answer.

Comment: No, you can ignore that--the important part is the "Clusterer" line.

Comment: Also, if you found this answer useful--would you do me a favor and mark it as the accepted answer?