# How to use dc.js with Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to use [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) with Emberjs framework. Unfortunately, I could not find any tutorial related to how to use dc.js with Ember.js. Any help related to it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919757/how-to-import-a-library-on-ember-js. I could successfully install dc.js using bower, how can I process ahead from here?

Comment: I don't know Ember in particular, but usually the strategy for integrating dc.js (or d3.js for that matter) with any framework is to split responsibility at the div level: let the framework handle the world outside, and let dc own everything inside the div. Does this help, or am I missing the point?

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for your reply. I understand your point. I am confused about how to let controllers and/or components of Emberjs handle necessary things like data loading, creating dimensions and groups. I am stuck at this point for quite a long time now.

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question, then? I imagine the solution will be to allow Ember to load the data, and then use Plain Old Javascript Code™ to set up your dimensions and groups. But maybe there are deeper integrations, I don't know. You'll have to ask a specific question to get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything specific as far as I know, at this time. But...

There is a shim here to import dc.js into Ember: https://github.com/Jbcampbe/ember-dc-shim

If you follow the Ember Guides on how to build a component and read through dc.js docs too, you should be able to work it out.

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/defining-a-component/